# how to upload video bigger than 25 mb- c#, javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a problem with uploading video in my project. 
If File has about 25mb then uploads good, but if I try to upload bigger file - 80 mb, I receive "failed".

Web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="104857600" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

My function in view file:

```
function createVideoUploader() {
        videoTempName = '@Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").Substring(0, 13)';
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('video-uploader'),
            allowedExtensions: ['3g2', '3gp', 'avi', 'f4v', 'flv', 'm4v', 'mov', 'mp4', 'mpeg', 'mpg', 'mts', 'ogv', 'webm', 'wmv'],
            sizeLimit: 838860800, //304857600,
            action: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Upload")',
            params: { 'fileTempName': videoTempName },
            multiple: false,
            onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {
                $('div.qq-upload-button').hide();
                $(".qq-upload-drop-area").remove();
            },
            onCancel: function() {
                createVideoUploader();
            },
            onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                if(responseJSON.success == false) {
                    uploaded = false;
                    $("#videoUploadedFail").show(); // show video error
                    var postData = { 'fileTempName': videoTempName };
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteTemp", "Upload")',
                        data: $.param(postData,true),
                        async: false
                    });
                } else if(responseJSON.success == true) {
                    uploaded = true;
                    $('div.qq-upload-button').hide();
                    var postData = { 'fileTempName': videoTempName };
                    $.post("@Url.Action("PreprocessVideo", "Upload")", $.param(postData,true),
                        function (data) {
                            appendSuccess("#flowVideo");
                            totalTime = secsToTime(data.seconds); // seconds to time
                            $("#duration").html(totalTime);
                            $(".timeText").html(totalTime);
                            $("#orderSlides").css("display", "inline-block");
                        });
                  }
            }
        });
        if (!($.browser.msie))
            $('span.qq-upload-span').append(' or drop file here');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS 7+ now requires you to also set the newer `requestFiltering/requestLimits/maxAllowedContentLength` attribute, and this has a default value for [`maxAllowedContentLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462.aspx) of `30000000` (which is approximately 28.4MB) which would fit with what you are seeing.

This should be set in conjunction with  the `httpRuntime/maxRequestLength` attribute to ensure that both IIS (via `maxAllowedContentLength` in bytes) and ASP.NET (via `maxRequestLength` in kilobytes) are in agreement.

You should be able to change this via the requestLimits element of your applications web.config to allow a more appropriate maximum:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

One thing to bear in mind though is that this is request filtering is performed server-side, once the content length has exceeded the limit - so there's nothing to stop the user attempting to upload a 150MB only to have it fail once 100.1MB have been uploaded.